# After reset group by column, column disapears, how to prevent this? TD 6.2

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase, centura

I populate my table from DB and then I right click on column and press group by, and it groups the rows, perfect, but when I reset/populate table again the column put in the group by disappears.

[image: After resetting blank space appears, and there is no column]

How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is not possible for table window and is possible only for Grids. Hope applying latest SPF will solve this issue. Which is available at 
[LINK](http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/Team_Developer_Downloads)